# mongodb backup script

Tags: macos, mongodb, backup

I need to run mongodump on my database everyday.

How do I automate this reasonably? Every day I want a new folder created with the timestamp and the dump data inside.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Look at

https://github.com/micahwedemeyer/automongobackup

Otherwise use standard tools like cron or shell scripting for wrapping the mongodump call.

Answer (score 1):

I have a super quick handy script. Sometimes I create a **cron** job for one of my database.

```
ssh root@hostname "mongodump --db myDatabaseName --out /tmp/mongo-backup ; zip -r /tmp/mongo-backup$(date "+%Y.%m.%d").zip  /tmp/mongo-backup ; rm -rf /tmp/mongo-backup" ;
scp root@hostname:/tmp/mongo-backup$(date "+%Y.%m.%d").zip ./
```

The above script does two things.

1. Runs the **mongodump** script and builds a ZIP file like: **mongo-backup2017.03.02.zip**
2. Downloads that file via SCP to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cron scheduler](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714) to run a mongodump shell script every day. Or you can even use iCal by creating an event, editing it, and selecting *Run Script*.